# iOS Game Center Combined Leaderboard Loading

Tags: ios, game-center

**Question:**

When loading scores from a combined leaderboard, how do I tell which source leaderboard the score originated from?

**Background:**

I am new to using iOS Game Center. I currently have three leaderboards; let's call them "level1", "level2" and a combined one called "aggregate". I submit scores like this, and it seems to work:

```
let score = GKScore(leaderboardIdentifier: "level1", player: localPlayer)
score.value = // Score here...
score.context = // Context here...
GKScore.reportScores([gcScore]) { error in
    // Error handling...
}
```

When I query to find a list of the top ten scores on all levels, I do this:

```
var leaderboard = GKLeaderboard()
leaderboard.identifier = "aggregate"
leaderboard.range = NSRange(location: 1, length: 10)
leaderboard.loadScoresWithCompletionHandler() { objects, error in
    // Error handling removed...
    let scores = objects as? [GKScore]
    // Examine the scores, looking at each score.leaderboardIdentifier to
    // determine where it originally came from.
}
```

Unfortunately, the leaderboardIdentifier on each score has the value "aggregate". I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if I'm missing something, but my understanding of [the leaderboard documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/LeaderBoards/LeaderBoards.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH6-SW32) makes it sound like this should be set to the original leaderboard value.

Any thoughts?